# how do i set categories one above the other, but with distinction in excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

please see the graph below:

[image]

I want the "closed" and "other closed" categories to be set one on top of the other, but keeping the distinction in grouping and color, thus resulting in to bar charts - one blue and the other, both orange and grey.

[image]

Comment: you could do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWmNLvq-O6k or https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/create-stacked-unstacked-column-chart-excel/

Comment: bingo!! thank you - exactly what I needed